# NUnit Tests not running in TeamCity, can't figure out why

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity-8.0

Here's my situation:

I'm trying to run NUnit tests on my .NET unit tests through TeamCity. I have a build step created for running the tests, with the following parameters:

```
Runner Type: NUnit
Step name: Run Unit Tests
Execute Step: If all previous steps finished correctly
NUnit runner: NUnit 2.6.3
.NET Runtime: auto (MSIL), Version v4.0
Run Tests From: {{path to the single .dll which contains all of my tests}}
```

I'm using MSBuild to build the project on a 64-bit Windows Server 2008 VM, and it compiles correctly. The build log output is as follows:

[image: screenshot of build log]

However, no tests tab pops up in TeamCity, and there is not evidence anywhere of the existence of test results. It seems like the tests are even running at all. Any advice?

Note: ignore the Step entitled "Run Unit Tests (Command Line)". That build step is disabled, and is an artifact of me trying to find a workaround for the problem I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was given misinformation - the .dll which contains the tests contains MSTest tests, not NUnit Tests. Once I changed the build runner type to MSTest, everything started working fine.